# Adding Border Line to UITableView in StoryBoard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I am working with my user interface in Xcode using Storyboard.

I would like to add a table view in the middle of my view controller. 
My problem is, the table will be shown without any border lines (Just cells separator lines).

Is there anyway to show the border lines?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just simple, Try this

```
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create IBOutlet of your table and write this code in your viewDidLoad

```
[tbl.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0] CGColor]];
[tbl.layer setBorderWidth:3.0f];
```

Answer (score 0):

Written on this code in your view did load methods and import the QuartzCore framework in the your .h file or .m file.

```
[tableView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
[tableView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[tableView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[tableView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
```

this might helps you :)